# Which test to determine if there is a difference between pharmacological reaction and population characteristic (e.g. ethnicity) in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, test-for-trend

I have a data set where each row represents an individual and their respective measure of pharmacological reaction (protein level) in addition to their epidemiologic characteristics (e.g. ethnicity, age, smoking status) .  I would like to statistically test if there are any significant differences in pharmacological reaction within an epidemiologic characteristic.  For an example, if there is a decrease in protein level in an Asian population, while no changes observed in a Caucasian population.

I have been using the DescTools package with the following command to create bivariate frequency tables: Desc (proteinLevel ~ ethnicity), but it isn't a statistical test.

My statistic skills are quite lacking, but I think a trend test may be appropriate. Do you have any suggestions or would plotting the bivariate frequencies suffice?

Comment: Just to be clear -- protein level (as recorded in the original data set) is ordered-categorical? Or is it some measured characteristic (e,g. a value in mmol/L or something)? Or something else?

Comment: Protein level is an ordered-categorical (it was originally a continuous variable, but transformed into 4 groups by quantiles)